# Connect to a device on another subnet using 3rd device as a proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, ssl, nginx

I have a device with a HTTPS web portal that only has an ethernet port. However I am unable to get an ethernet cable to the where the device lives, it is however able to receive WiFi.

I was planing on using a raspberry Pi or laptop with an ethernet and WiFi Nic cards on it.

I am testing with a Linux laptop using eno1 and wlp2s0 to connect to the WiFi

My WiFi network is 192.168.1.x the device in on 192.168.4.x

I tired using Nginx, this work great for HTTP using

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name 192.168.1.80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.4.101/;
    }
}
```

However to use for HTTPS I would need a SSL certificate. However it does not appear I can generate one for an ip-address plus the SSL would only be for that Nginx server. I imagine using a Nginx server will terminate the HTTPS request and the SSL certificate for the device I want to connect will not be valid.

Is Nginx the the right technology for doing this? If not what can I use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unable to get an ethernet cable to the where the device lives, it is however able to receive WiFi.

There are many products that can connect to a Wi-Fi network and provide access via Ethernet, allowing the Ethernet-connected devices to directly be on the same IP subnet; often they're sold as "Wi-Fi extenders" or "wireless bridges". I can't really say anything about their reliability, however.

(Making one out of a Linux device is unfortunately somewhat difficult; for something that approximates 'true bridging' it needs to do ARPNAT/L2NAT and I don't think iptables or ebtables can do that?)

> However to use for HTTPS I would need a SSL certificate. However it does not appear I can generate one for an ip-address

You said that the device has an HTTPS web portal, and most likely it already has a certificate, which means Nginx can also have a certificate in the same way. Even if you generate a bogus self-signed certificate, you'll still be *at worst* in the same situation as if speaking HTTPS directly to the device, not worse than that.

So if the device has a self-signed certificate for its IP address, you can in fact generate one for Nginx as well; if the device has a self-signed certificate for "domain-not-filled-in.tld.invalid", you can generate one for Nginx too. (If you have internal DNS – you can generate a cert for a domain name, etc.)

If you don't really care about HTTPS, then Nginx does not need a certificate at all; it works as an HTTP proxy (which is why it terminates SSL in the first place) so it can in fact proxy between HTTP and HTTPS or vice versa. Just change the proxy_pass to an https:// URL and it'll talk to the device via SSL without having its own certificate.

> Is Nginx the the right technology for doing this? If not what can I use to do this?

It would probably be easier to set up DNAT in iptables or nftables – i.e. the same "port forwarding" as you have on your router – so that the entire TCP connection would be relayed end-to-end, without any changes in SSL. You can add a DNAT rule that redirects packets for port 443, and then connecting to https://YourPi will open the device's interface, without any extra software.

(But that means the device would need to terminate SSL using a certificate valid for the Pi's IP address, which probably won't improve the situation.)